# Groovy override 'or' for Integer to 'or' with another Integer

Tags: groovy

In Groovy everything is Object, even numbers

```
assert 1.getClass() == Integer
```

In Groovy you can override existing method in an existing class in runtime

```
Integer.metaClass.or = { right -> println "$delegate or $right" }
```

Now we can call or operator on any number using pipe (|)

```
1.or("hello") // prints: 1 or hello
1 | "hello" // prints: 1 or hello
```

So far so good. Now let's try to **or** an Integer with an Integer

```
2.or(3) // nothing happens
2 | 3 // nothing happens
```

This leads us to my **questions**:

- Why nothing happens?
- Is this an optimization bug?
- How to make it work for any type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably choosing an already existing `or` method that takes an integer, rather than your more generic Object version.

Does it work if you do:

```
Integer.metaClass.or = { Integer right -> println "$delegate or $right" }
```

Not at a computer at the moment though, so can't validate this :-/

Comment: Do you know how to override all of the overloaded or with one custom without using Categories?

Comment: The `or` method seems to be available in three places. Once for [Boolean](https://github.com/groovy/groovy-core/blob/master/src/main/org/codehaus/groovy/runtime/DefaultGroovyMethods.java#L10439), once for [Number](https://github.com/groovy/groovy-core/blob/master/src/main/org/codehaus/groovy/runtime/DefaultGroovyMethods.java#L9405) and once for [BitSet](https://github.com/groovy/groovy-core/blob/master/src/main/org/codehaus/groovy/runtime/DefaultGroovyMethods.java#L9472).  To override with a single method, you would need to have all 3 of these typed closures delegate to a single method.